# How does the browser process image sources?

Tags: javascript, canvas

**[UPDATE]** I found two links useful to me:

> http://mrcoles.com/blog/canvas-composite-operations-demo-animation/
>
> http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/composition.html

Recently when I learn canvas, I find there is more than one way to specify the image `src`:

1. You can give a image-URI, like : `www.XYZ.com/abc.png`
2. You can give a data-URI, like: `data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ hexcode;`
3. You can give a data-URI from canvas like: `canvas.toDataURL("image/png");`

I am a little confused about what the difference among them and wondering how browser processes them?

Thanks

Comment: there's several others too, but it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I think you've answered you own question! There are multiple way to tell the browser where to get the image data. In each case, the browser will create a new Image object and try to fetch the image data based on the image.src.  All of them will result in an image object being created from the image data (regardless of where that image data was found).

Comment: @markE thanks, so no matter what being set to src, it will eventually converted into dataURL(like data:image/png.....)?

Comment: You can look this article, it explains how the HTML parsing works (general idea) http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply a matter of what the browser supports. The browser will look at the protocol header of the string and if it recognizes it try to interpret it. For example:

If it starts with "http://" or "https://" it will parse the rest of the string with that as a basis. Then try to connect using the HTTP(S) protocol to the server and communicate over this protocol. The protocol itself is specified in RFCs. If all OK, then data is transferred from server to browser which then goes to the next step interpreting the received data itself (this can happen during or after the data has loaded completely).

If the string starts with "data:" the browser will assume a Data-URI protocol (if it supports this protocol). If not, it will consider the source invalid. As it does not need to connect to any external resources in this case, it will validate the content of it and use it if valid. Data-URI will be converted to binary data (the base-64 representation will be converted back to binary form).

(2. and 3. are the same BTW. It's not hexcode that is appended, but a base-64 encoded string, ie. ASCII representation. Other representations are possible but not common).

Then there are other protocols which the browser may support, such as Blob-URL and perhaps some browser will allow FTP (ftp://), and some allow file:// given certain restrictions.

Comment: so, the "http format src" has no relationship with "dataURI format src", they are just separated protocols?  The data fetch from http src will not convert into dataURI but go to interpreting phase, and so is DataURI, it is also go to intercepting phase?

Comment: @Kuan data-uri carry the data itself so there is no need to fetch it (it's more a pseudo-protocol, a formatted string, but a protocol header makes it easy to detect). other protocols will not be converted to data-uri, but have data interpreted directly (for images always binary data). data-uri is just a way to carry binary data as string and is not related to the other protocols per-se.